# When is the screenshot taken for the app drawer?

Tags: android, onpause

I have an app with a login page.  In the login page, I have a switch to allow the user to show the password they are entering in plain text to ensure they are entering it correctly.  However, when I pause the app and the app goes into the background, a screenshot is taken and the plain text password can be seen in the app drawer.

I tried adding a statement in the onPause() method of the activity to turn off the Hide/Show switch before pausing.  You can see the password revert back to a masked password before the app pauses, but the screenshot still shows the plain text password.

So I'm wondering when the screenshot for the app drawer is taken and whether I can get the password switched back to masked before that happens.

I know about the FLAG_SECURE window flags but that creates a black app drawer screenshot and I would prefer to give something more user-friendly to the user.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: With security, function takes priority over aesthetics. It might be better to use `FLAG_SECURE` than to protect passwords with a dubious technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want is not supported. There is a method in Activity called `onCreateThumbnail()` that can be overridden to provide a custom thumbnail, but according to a post from Dianne Hackborn in 2009, this method is never actually called:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/J5uBtHzhG8E/bX43j_GAm4gJ

I've tried it relatively recently myself to no effect, so I have to assume that's still the case.